# Кто такой ушлепок?

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Есть такое ругательство "ушлепок" (гад, негодяй и т. д.). А мне вот стало интересно, откуда оно вообще произошло? Кого и чем шлепают?

Спасибо!

Comment: На этот вопрос может точно ответить только автор этого слова

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А. РАЗГОВОРЫ В ИНТЕРНЕТЕ

ЕСТЬ ЛИ ТАКОЕ СЛОВО

В словаре нет слова "ушлёпок",  очень популярного в нашем регионе. - Ха, а я-то всерьез полагал, что я это слово сам придумал! А оно, оказывается, и без меня популярно. 
Это слово вначале кажется безумно глупым и бессмысленным, но вскоре привязывается крепко и надолго.

ПРИМЕРЫ

Его звали презрительно - ушлёпок. Держись подальше от этого ушлепка, он опасен трусостью своей и ничтожеством. Вот тебя, ушлепка, забыл спросить, чего мне делать.Будет очень обидно, что твой труд какой-то тупой ушлепок подправил по своим критериям. Ушлёпка, вроде меня, всяк может обидеть.

ЗНАЧЕНИЕ

Лох,  лошок, неудачник, раздолбай, тупой, бесполезный, глупый, растяпа, неудачник, 
Не знаю, почему именно это слово пришло мне в голову при первой встрече, но это идеальная характеристика этого парня, правда.
Ушлёпок- самое безобидное из ругательных слов, это что-то вроде английского silly

ПРОИСХОЖДЕНИЕ

Наверное слово “ушлёпок” произошло вследствие вопроса: «Ты с дуба рухнул (или шлёпнулся)».

Б. ОРИГИНАЛЬНАЯ ЧАСТЬ (КТО ОНИ ТАКИЕ)

Но почему же всё-таки ушлепок?  Ушлепок – это, по видимому, «ушлёпнутый» (сравнить: "забитый" - запуганный, отупелый), если считать, что "шлёпать" – это наносить удары, побои ладонью или чем-л. мягким (обычно не сильно). Приставка У красноречиво свидетельствует о результативности процесса.

Ушлепок – загадочное слово. Так называют нестандартных людей, вызывающих своим поведением чувство неприязни. Их не понимают, но при этом не уважают за оригинальность, а презирают. Кажется, что это собирательный образ человека, который не может вписаться в окружающую действительность.

А какие они, эти ушлепки,  на самом деле? Они действительно заслуживают пренебрежительно-презрительного отношения? Если люди  нестандартные, оригинальные, разве это плохие качества?

Скорее всего,  особое мироощущение и оригинальность  должны присутствовать в  человеке, но при этом не должны досаждать окружающим. Непредсказуемость в обычном и повседневном всегда настораживает и вызывает негативные эмоции. Наверное, с ушлепками трудно иметь дело.